# How to force WebFaultException to return custom error?

Tags: wcf, rest

I have working WCF REST web service and can set status codes and status descriptions as usual:

```
OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
response.StatusCode = statusCode;
response.StatusDescription = detail.Error;
```

But I want to use WebFaultException. Unfortunately it alvays return {"Detail":"Not Found"} when I run my code:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class DtoError
{
    public DtoError()
    {

    }
    public DtoError(string error)
    {
        Error = error;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Error { get; private set; }
}

var error = new DtoError(entityName + " is not existing");
throw new WebFaultException<DtoError>(error, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

Can I return my custom error json object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I found that instead of WebServiceHost we are using WebServiceHost2 from Rest Starter Kit. And inside that host we have to use WebProtocolException. So now my working code looks like that:

```
throw new WebProtocolException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not Found", error, null);
```

Comment: My issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949748/wcf-restful-service-post-webfaultexception-complete-sample.. I found ProtocolException not WebProtocolException..